# how Validate a teacher's record in a course and a PHP section?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a consultation that is giving me some headaches. I am making a system where I register courses (violin, guitar, flute ...) and each course will have a section (section A, section B, section C ...). Each course will have a day and a schedule for related shifts according to the section (if it is section A it will be only Monday and Wednesday from 8am to 12 pm..if it is section B it will be Tuesday and Thursday from 3pm to 5pm, and so ..) .

The problem comes at the moment of registering a teacher in a section and a course, once I register the teacher, I through a combobox I can select after filling the information of the section with their hours and days, my question Is how can I prevent a teacher who is already in a course from 8am to 12pm only Mondays and Wednesdays can not be registered again for example in a section C where are Tuesday and Wednesday at the same time as section A? I want to avoid is the clash of hours per teacher when registering in a section and course.

A teacher can give many courses, but not in the same shift (morning-evening) the same day. But he can give one course in the morning shift and another in the afternoon shift.

For now I have my DB in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE `seccion` (
  `id_seccion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horaEntrada` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horaSalida` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dias` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cupos` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `curso_id_curso` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personas_cedula` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `turno` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And try to do the following, but as I said, it gives me headaches already as I place this I consult:

```
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(personas_cedula) FROM seccion WHERE personas_cedula='$cbx_profesor' AND turno='matutino' AND dias='$dias' AND horaEntrada='$horaEntrada'  ");
                    $row = @mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
                    if($row[0]>=1){


                        $errors[] = "El profesor ya se encuentra registrado en un curso";

                    } else {





  $sql = "INSERT INTO seccion (descripcion, horaEntrada, horaSalida, dias,cupos,curso_id_curso,personas_cedula,turno) VALUES('$descripcion','$horaEntrada','$horaSalida','$dias','$cupos','$cbx_curso','$cbx_profesor','$turno')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Who can help me, I would appreciate it in advance!

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that are trying to point out serious problems.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Also those fields are really, really short. Try using `VARCHAR(255)` as a default for generic "string" fields. Ten characters is extremely restrictive.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that one section can be taught by two different teachers? For example if we have section A Then one teacher wilk have lessons on Monday and another on Wednesday?

Comment: I think you should provide new object named "lesson" then you will make schedule for all lessons connected with instruments for every week, two weeks or month. After that some lessons you will group with sections. Students can assigns to section and they can check how many lessons it takes. Teachers cannot assign to sections but they can assign to lessons. This should help. Give me feedback what do you think about it?

Comment: It seems like each course may have several sections

Comment: I think that there is relation one course and one section. Sections only helps students to select best possible time for them.